# How to create a jks with .key file

Tags: java, certificate, ws-security, digital-certificate

I have a .key file created from another team and they have generated .csr from

that .key file using openssl.

The cer and .pem files have been shared once they were signed by authorities

Could you please let me know how to

a) generate a jks file with the .key(private)

b) what files (.cer/.pem needs to be added to the jks which has the private key

I have already added the .cer file to the jks which has other teams public certs.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this using only OpenSSL, but I use KeyStore Explorer: http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/

It can examine, import, and export certificates as well as key pairs, and it makes changing the keystore format a trivial matter. I use it all the time to take Microsoft .pfx files and turn them into JKS keystore files for use with Tomcat and JBoss.